# What is the difference between reflect.ValueOf() and Value.Elem() in go?

Tags: go, pointers, reflection, interface

I started learning golang a couple of days ago and found [reflect.Valueof()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) and [Value.Elem()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) quite confusing. What is the difference between this two function/methods and how to use them correctly?

Both function/methods return a Value, and according to the go doc

> ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to the concrete value stored in the interface i. ValueOf(nil) returns the zero Value.
>
> Elem returns the value that the interface v contains or that the pointer v points to. It panics if v's Kind is not Interface or Ptr. It returns the zero Value if v is nil.

I found this code from a post on stackoverflow but still don't understand when to use .Elem()

```golang
func SetField(obj interface{}, name string, value interface{}) error {
    
    // won't work if I remove .Elem()
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj).Elem()
    
    structFieldValue := structValue.FieldByName(name)

    if !structFieldValue.IsValid() {
        return fmt.Errorf("No such field: %s in obj", name)
    }

    if !structFieldValue.CanSet() {
        return fmt.Errorf("Cannot set %s field value", name)
    }

    structFieldType := structFieldValue.Type()

    // won't work either if I add .Elem() to the end
    val := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if structFieldType != val.Type() {

        return fmt.Errorf("Provided value %v type %v didn't match obj field type %v",val,val.Type(),structFieldType)
    }

    structFieldValue.Set(val)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) is a *function*, think of it as the entry point to reflection. When you have a "non-reflection" value, such as a `string` or `int`, you can use `reflect.ValueOf()` to get a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) descriptor of it.

[`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) is a *method* of `reflect.Value`. So you can only use this if you already have a `reflect.Value`. You may use `Value.Elem()` to get the value (`reflect.Value`) pointed by the value wrapped by the original `reflect.Value`. Note that you may also use [`reflect.Indirect()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect) for this. There's another "use case" for `Value.Elem()`, but it's more "advanced", we return to it at the end of the answer.

To "leave" reflection, you may use the general [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method, which returns you the wrapped value as an `interface{}`.

For example:

```
var i int = 3
var p *int = &i
fmt.Println(p, i)

v := reflect.ValueOf(p)
fmt.Println(v.Interface()) // This is the p pointer

v2 := v.Elem()
fmt.Println(v2.Interface()) // This is i's value: 3
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qpb0OMLEros)):

```
0x414020 3
0x414020
3
```

For a great introduction to Go's reflection, read [The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection). Although if you're just starting with Go, I'd focus on other things and leave reflection for a later adventure.

### Another use case for `Value.Elem()`

*This is kind of an advanced topic, so don't freak out if you don't understand it. You don't need to.*

We saw how `Value.Elem()` can be used to "navigate" when a pointer is wrapped in the `reflect.Value`. Doc of `Value.Elem()` says:

> Elem returns the value that the interface v contains or that the pointer v points to.

So if `reflect.Value` wraps an interface value, `Value.Elem()` may also be used to get the concrete value wrapped in that interface value.

Interfaces in Go is its own topic, for the internals, you may read [Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) by Russ Cox. Again, not necessarily a topic for Go starters.

Basically whatever value you pass to `reflect.ValueOf()`, if it's not already an interface value, it will be wrapped in an `interface{}` implicitly. If the passed value is already an interface value, then the concrete value stored in it will be passed as a `interface{}`. This second "use case" surfaces if you pass a pointer to interface (which is otherwise very rare in Go!).

So if you pass a pointer to interface, this pointer will be wrapped in an `interface{}` value. You may use `Value.Elem()` to get the pointed value, which will be an interface value (not a concrete value), and using `Value.Elem()` *again* on this will give you the concrete value.

This example illustrates it:

```
var r io.Reader = os.Stdin // os.Stdin is of type *os.File which implements io.Reader

v := reflect.ValueOf(r) // r is interface wrapping *os.File value
fmt.Println(v.Type())   // *os.File

v2 := reflect.ValueOf(&r)            // pointer passed, will be wrapped in interface{}
fmt.Println(v2.Type())               // *io.Reader
fmt.Println(v2.Elem().Type())        // navigate to pointed: io.Reader (interface type)
fmt.Println(v2.Elem().Elem().Type()) // 2nd Elem(): get concrete value in interface: *os.File
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JeJV-4Ij5u-).

Comment: It seems to me that the Value returned by reflect.ValueOf() is like the file header containing all necessary metadata, while the Value returned by Value.Elem() is the actual file body?

Comment: @stevenh6140 No, not really. In my first example I have an `i` variable of `int` type, and a `p` variable of pointer to `int` type, pointing to `i`. If you call `Elem()` on `p`'s `reflect.Value`, you get a `reflect.Value`, something you would have gotten if you'd call `reflect.ValueOf()` on `i` in the first place.

Comment: @icza great answer, it cleared a lot of my confusion about reflection `Value`, thanks for taking out time to write it!