# Are there official words about what type is an interface type in Go?

Tags: go, types, interface

This is a Go grammar question and seems a stupid question but I've been checking the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) to find some official words or definitions to define what type is a xxx type, say, what type is an interface type?

For example, I see words like these:

> The method set of ***an interface type*** is its interface.

Or

> An embedded field must be specified as a type name T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not be ***a pointer type***.

Or

> Consider ***a struct type*** T with two methods ...

```
type T struct {
  a int
}
....
```

A type literal like `struct {...}` is a struct type, what about `A` in 
`type A struct {...}` and `B` in `type B interface{...}`? Is `A` a struct type and `B` an interface type?

Yes, from the above sample for the struct type `T`, I can tell that a defined type (by the "type" declaration) whose given type is a struct type or interface type is also a struct or interface type. So `A` is a struct type and `B` is an interface type also. But where are the official definitions of this rule?

For defined types I can only find the following relating to type categories:

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.

So my understanding is that the defined type is a new, distinct type with the given type, but they are in the same type category, say, interface types or struct types. Still, there are no such definitions.

Comment: What definitions are you looking for, or specifically what would you expect? Each specification is in the same doc: [Interface Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) and [Struct Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). Since the implications of what you quote seem obvious, what further explanation does it need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR;**

> The **kind** of type `T` is *interface* if its underlying type is an interface type.
>
> The **kind** of type `T` is *struct* if its underlying type is a struct type.

---

[Spec: Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and [Spec: Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) specifies exactly what are the struct and interface types:

> ```
> StructType    = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
> FieldDecl     = (IdentifierList Type | EmbeddedField) [ Tag ] .
> EmbeddedField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
> Tag           = string_lit .
>
> InterfaceType      = "interface" "{" { MethodSpec ";" } "}" .
> MethodSpec         = MethodName Signature | InterfaceTypeName .
> MethodName         = identifier .
> InterfaceTypeName  = TypeName .
> ```

So for example these are struct types:

```
struct { A int }
struct {}
struct { _ int }
```

and these are interface types:

```
interface { String() string }
interface {}
```

We may use a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) to create a new type, such as:

```
type Point struct { X, Y int }
```

The above *type definition* creates a new, distinct type with the same [underlying type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it. The definition of *underlying type* is recursive:

> Each type `T` has an *underlying type*: If `T` is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the corresponding underlying type is `T` itself. Otherwise, `T`'s underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which `T` refers in its [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

When we talk about arbitrary types being structs or interfaces, we're talking about their *kind*.

In the light of this, basically your question is equivalent to this:

*"When is the **kind** of an arbitrary type interface or struct?"*

The answer to this question is not in the spec, but this is how we could define it:

> The **kind** of a type `T` is *interface* if its underlying type is an interface type.

Similarly:

> The **kind** of a type `T` is *struct* if its underlying type is a struct type.

So for example:

```
type Point struct { X, Y int }

type PP Point
```

Is the type `struct { X, Y int }` of kind *struct*? Yes, because since it's a type literal, its underlying type is itself, and it's by definition a struct type.

Is `Point` a struct? Since the underlying type of `Point` is the underlying type of the type to which it refers in its type declaration, which is a type literal (see above), it is of struct type (its *kind* is struct).

Is `PP` a struct? Since its underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which it refers in its type declaration (which is `Point`), whose underlying type is a struct type literal, yes, it is also a struct type.

This *kind* we're talking about is represented by the [`reflect.Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) type. There are `reflect.Interface` and `reflect.Struct` constants (of type `reflect.Kind`) to represent the *struct* and *interface* kinds. And the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) type descriptor has a `Type.Kind()` method to access this kind.

This is how you can check if the type (kind) of some value is a struct for example:

```
func isStruct(i interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind() == reflect.Struct
}
```

Testing it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7wYM6kdE-Lm)):

```
fmt.Println(isStruct(Point{}))    // true
fmt.Println(isStruct(PP{}))       // true
fmt.Println(isStruct(struct{}{})) // true
fmt.Println(isStruct("text"))     // false
```

<sup>Checking for interface type is a little more complicated because passing an interface value to a function that expects `interface{}` will not pass the interface value as-is but the concrete value "stored" in it, and as an `interface{}` value. We would have to pass a pointer to interface (which otherwise rarely makes sense in Go), access the element type and check its kind. For details, see this answer: [What is the difference between reflect.ValueOf() and Value.Elem() in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388657/what-is-the-difference-between-reflect-valueof-and-value-elem-in-go/57388715#57388715)</sup>

Comment: Yes, `The kind of a type T is interface if its underlying type is an interface type.    The kind of a type T is struct if its underlying type is a struct type.` These words are sort of what I'm looking for in the spec, just want to get an official definition or statement to say so. But as I can tell from your answer there are no such words, it's not I missed it:).

Answer (score 1):

An interface *type* is a type introduced by the `interface` keyword, or a name for such a type as defined by `type name interface` (plus of course the actual requirements for that interface).

Any type, whether it is an interface type or not, *implements* an interface type if it has the appropriate set of named methods.  That is, a `struct` type may be sufficient to be used with some interface type.  Even a non-`struct` type may be sufficient:

```
type foo int
func (receiver_arg foo) method1() { ... }
```

Type-name `foo` now *implements* any interface that requires a method named `method1` (provided of course that it implements the rest of any required methods).

> ... the defined type [via the `type` keyword] is a new, distinct type with the given type, but they are in the same type category ...

Yes, just so.  Using `reflect`, you'll find that they have the same [`Kind`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind).  The word *kind* isn't in the spec like this but it's quite useful, and the link here enumerates all the fundamental type-kinds in Go.