# Can I pass an *io.ReadCloser to a parameter with the type of *io.Reader

Tags: go

I am trying to write a function with a parameter of type `*io.Reader`

```
func ReadSomething(r *io.Reader) {
    <do something with a reader>
}
```

but then when I try to pass in a pointer to a reader closer to it

```
func GetWebPage() {
    resp, _ := http.Get(<url>)
    ReadSomething(&(resp.Body))
}
```

I get the following error: `cannot use &(resp.Body) (value of type *io.ReadCloser) as *io.Reader value`.

This makes no sense to me, a dereferenced pointer to a read closer type *should* implement the methods of `Reader`, so why am I not able then to pass it in as an argument to a function that expects a pointer to an `io.Reader`?

Comment: Do not use pointer to interfaces. Pointers to interface do have their use but this is a very limited, rare use case. Almost no code ever needs or even benefits from pointers to an interface.

Answer (score 3):

`io.ReadCloser` is an interface type that is a superset of `io.Reader` interface type. So whenever an `io.Reader` is required, you may pass a value of `io.ReadCloser`.

`*io.Reader` is not an interface type though, it's a pointer (a pointer to interface), so you can't pass `*io.ReadCloser`.

Please note that these function signatures are a terrible design. You rarely need a pointer to interface (you'll know when you do, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388657/what-is-the-difference-between-reflect-valueof-and-value-elem-in-go/57388715#57388715) for an example). Just use interface types, interfaces may wrap pointers if needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misconception in Go that interfaces are more magical and gluey than they really are. As a starting point, all conversions between distinct types must be explicit, and interfaces are distinct types.

Interfaces only carve out a narrow exception to this rule:

[Assignability Rules in the Go Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) (which extends to parameter passing).

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if [...]
>
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.

Or in other words, simple and plain:

> x is assignable to T if x implements T.

That's really the whole entire exception, and it makes no expansive effort to generally mesh interfaces, implementations, and structures thereof. As soon as you indirect your interface value through a pointer, you have stepped out of the enumerated territory.